# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this error in my MVC3 Application. Please Help...

Error :

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'`

On Line:

`string desigId = HttpContext.Current.Session["Desig_Id"].ToString();`

the code with its method in class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers
{
    public class NotificationController : Controller
    {
        //to send email notification
        [Authorize]
        public static string SendEmailNotification(int crmId, string username, string action)
        {

              string desigId = HttpContext.Current.Session["Desig_Id"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your base class `Controller` already implements a property [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

You can either reference it fully qualified: [`System.Web.HttpContext.Current...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or use the Property of your controller, just like `HttpContext.Session`. For the second option, your method must be `non-static` though.

Comment: It would be nice if you were to link to the english version of the documentation instead of the german.

Answer (score 2):

One more reason for the error is that you can't use `HttpContext.Current.Session` and `Server.MapPath()` in static method

In such case you can make use of `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`